# Terraform destroys the instance inside RDS cluster when upgrading

Tags: terraform, amazon-rds, terraform-provider-aws

I have created a RDS cluster with 2 instances using terraform. When I am upgrading the RDS from front-end, it modifies the cluster. But when I do the same using terraform, it destroys the instance.

We tried create_before_destroy, and it gives error.

We tried with ignore_changes=engine but that didn't make any changes.

Is there any way to prevent it?

```
resource "aws_rds_cluster" "rds_mysql" {
  cluster_identifier              = var.cluster_identifier
  engine                          = var.engine
  engine_version                  = var.engine_version
  engine_mode                     = var.engine_mode
  availability_zones              = var.availability_zones
  database_name                   = var.database_name
  port                            = var.db_port
  master_username                 = var.master_username
  master_password                 = var.master_password
  backup_retention_period         = var.backup_retention_period
  preferred_backup_window         = var.engine_mode == "serverless" ? null : var.preferred_backup_window
  db_subnet_group_name            = var.create_db_subnet_group == "true" ? aws_db_subnet_group.rds_subnet_group[0].id : var.db_subnet_group_name
  vpc_security_group_ids          = var.vpc_security_group_ids
  db_cluster_parameter_group_name = var.create_cluster_parameter_group == "true" ? aws_rds_cluster_parameter_group.rds_cluster_parameter_group[0].id : var.cluster_parameter_group
  skip_final_snapshot             = var.skip_final_snapshot
  deletion_protection             = var.deletion_protection
  allow_major_version_upgrade     = var.allow_major_version_upgrade
  lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = false
    ignore_changes        = [availability_zones]
  }
}

resource "aws_rds_cluster_instance" "cluster_instances" {
  count                      = var.engine_mode == "serverless" ? 0 : var.cluster_instance_count
  identifier                 = "${var.cluster_identifier}-${count.index}"
  cluster_identifier         = aws_rds_cluster.rds_mysql.id
  instance_class             = var.instance_class
  engine                     = var.engine
  engine_version             = aws_rds_cluster.rds_mysql.engine_version
  db_subnet_group_name       = var.create_db_subnet_group == "true" ? aws_db_subnet_group.rds_subnet_group[0].id : var.db_subnet_group_name
  db_parameter_group_name    = var.create_db_parameter_group == "true" ? aws_db_parameter_group.rds_instance_parameter_group[0].id : var.db_parameter_group
  apply_immediately          = var.apply_immediately
  auto_minor_version_upgrade = var.auto_minor_version_upgrade
  lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = false
    ignore_changes        = [engine_version]
  }
}
```

Error:

```
resource \"aws_rds_cluster_instance\" \"cluster_instances\" {\n\n\n\nError: error creating RDS Cluster (aurora-cluster-mysql) Instance: DBInstanceAlreadyExists: DB instance already exists\n\tstatus code: 400, request id: c6a063cc-4ffd-4710-aff2-eb0667b0774f\n\n on
```

Plan output:

```
Terraform used the selected providers to generate the following execution plan. Resource actions are indicated with the following symbols:
  ~ update in-place
+/- create replacement and then destroy

Terraform will perform the following actions:

  # module.rds_aurora_create[0].aws_rds_cluster.rds_mysql will be updated in-place
  ~ resource "aws_rds_cluster" "rds_mysql" {
      ~ allow_major_version_upgrade         = false -> true
      ~ engine_version                      = "5.7.mysql_aurora.2.07.1" -> "5.7.mysql_aurora.2.08.1"
        id                                  = "aurora-cluster-mysql"
        tags                                = {}
        # (33 unchanged attributes hidden)
    }

  # module.rds_aurora_create[0].aws_rds_cluster_instance.cluster_instances[0] must be replaced
+/- resource "aws_rds_cluster_instance" "cluster_instances" {
      ~ arn                             = "arn:aws:rds:us-east-1:account:db:aurora-cluster-mysql-0" -> (known after apply)
      ~ availability_zone               = "us-east-1a" -> (known after apply)
      ~ ca_cert_identifier              = "rds-ca-" -> (known after apply)
      ~ dbi_resource_id                 = "db-32432432SDF" -> (known after apply)
      ~ endpoint                        = "aurora-cluster-mysql-0.jkjk.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com" -> (known after apply)
      ~ engine_version                  = "5.7.mysql_aurora.2.07.1" -> "5.7.mysql_aurora.2.08.1" # forces replacement
      ~ id                              = "aurora-cluster-mysql-0" -> (known after apply)
      + identifier_prefix               = (known after apply)
      + kms_key_id                      = (known after apply)
      + monitoring_role_arn             = (known after apply)
      ~ performance_insights_enabled    = false -> (known after apply)
      + performance_insights_kms_key_id = (known after apply)
      ~ port                            = 3306 -> (known after apply)
      ~ preferred_backup_window         = "07:00-09:00" -> (known after apply)
      ~ preferred_maintenance_window    = "thu:06:12-thu:06:42" -> (known after apply)
      ~ storage_encrypted               = false -> (known after apply)
      - tags                            = {} -> null
      ~ tags_all                        = {} -> (known after apply)
      ~ writer                          = true -> (known after apply)
        # (12 unchanged attributes hidden)
    }

Plan: 1 to add, 1 to change, 1 to destroy.
```

Comment: Between which version and which? Please add some code on your exact TF config regarding the cluster and instances + full `terraform plan` output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see `apply_immediately` argument not there in  `aws_rds_cluster` resource , can you add that and try.

Answer (score 2):

Terraform is seeing the engine version change on the instances and is detecting this as an action that forces replacement.

**Remove (or ignore changes to) the `engine_version` input for the `aws_rds_cluster_instance` resources.**

AWS RDS upgrades the engine version for cluster instances *itself* when you upgrade the engine version of the cluster (this is why you can do an in-place upgrade via the AWS console).

By excluding the `engine_version` input, Terraform will see no changes made to the `aws_rds_cluster_instance`s and will do nothing.

AWS will handle the engine upgrades for the instances internally.

---

If you decide to ignore changes, use the [`ignore_changes`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/meta-arguments/lifecycle.html#ignore_changes) argument within a `lifecycle` block:

```
resource "aws_rds_cluster_instance" "cluster_instance" {
  engine_version     = aws_rds_cluster.main.engine_version
  ...

  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes        = [engine_version]
  }
}
```

Comment: We tried this. The code is creating new DBInstance and failing instead of modifying them. I have added code and error in the question above.

Comment: Any update here , m looking for the same answer

Comment: @MayaRay Ah your Q was lacking code - can you please add the exact output of terraform plan to the question? I can then advise

Comment: Added the plan output. Please check.

Comment: @MayaRay Does removing the engine version completely fix this? Also what Terraform version are you on?

Comment: removing engine_version in aws_rds_cluster_instance doesnt help  it gives the same error , tries to create instance and then fails with error instance already exists. Terraform version 0.14.8

Comment: Okay - you may have a bug in your Terraform version; can you upgrade to 0.15 and see if the issue still persists? Is that possible?

Comment: With Terraform version 0.15.1 it gets successful with one change but no changes in console

Answer (score 1):

I didn't know that, but after some Googling I found this:
https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/issues/10714

i.e. a bug report to AWS Terraform provider:

> resource/aws_rds_cluster_instance is being destroyed and re-created when updating engine_version while apply_immediately is set to false

which seems to be the very same issue you are facing.

One comment there seems to point to a solution:

> As of v3.63.0 (EDITED) of the provider, updates to the engine_version parameter of aws_rds_cluster_instance resources no longer forces replacement of the resource.

The original comment seems to have a typo - 3.36 vs. 3.63.

Can you try upgrading your `aws` Terraform provider?

Comment: We tried with terraform version 14.8 and aws provider version 3.63 . It says modification complete but it doesn't make any changes in console.

Comment: Seems like a feedback to the provider team?